# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have referenced Jquery in my visualforce page and i'm getting the following error:
[image]

Here is my visualforce page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<apex:form id="basic_form"> 
<apex:pageblock >
<!-- The action function which calles the Apex function 'autosave' -->
<apex:actionFunction name="autosave" action="{!autosave}" rerender="out" status="savestatus"/>

<!-- A status denotion of the update -->
<apex:actionStatus id="savestatus">
          <apex:facet name="start"> Auto Saving....<img src="/img/loading.gif"/> </apex:facet> 
</apex:actionStatus>

<apex:pageblocksection columns="2">
      <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Name}"/>
      <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.BillingCity}"/>
      <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.BillingCountry}"/>
      <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.BillingState}"/>
</apex:pageblocksection>      
</apex:pageblock>

<!-- A javascript recursive function which calls itself every 10 seconds, the setTimeout method calls the apex function 'autosave' defined in the <apex:actionfunction> tag above -->
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.sisyphusf, '/sisyphusf/sisyphus.min.js')}"/>

<script>
// $( function() {
// $( "#basic_form" ).sisyphus();
// alert('changed');
// // or you can persist all forms data at one command
// // $( "form" ).sisyphus();
// } );
//           window.setTimeout(recursivecall,10000);
//           function recursivecall()
//           {
//               window.setTimeout(recursivecall,10000);
//               autosave();
//           }    
</script>

</apex:form>      
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using [apex:includeScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_includeScript.htm), the sisyphusf script loading is moved to the beginning of the page:

> When specified, this component injects a script reference into the
>    element of the generated HTML page.

which is before the jQuery script has been loaded.

Use the same loading mechanism for both e.g. `apex:includeScript` so they load in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

After update code looks like this

```
<apex:page ... >

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.sisyphusf, '/sisyphusf/sisyphus.min.js')}"><script>

    <!-- other markup -->
</apex:page>
```